# Reset itemindex of an item in AdvOfficeRadioGroup1 (TMS component)

Tags: delphi, tms

How can I set the item index of an item in AdvOfficeRadioGroup1 to -1 when I uncheck the checkbox? Unchecking disables the items but the selection is still visible.

Edit :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach this code:

```
PROCEDURE TMainForm.AdvOfficeRadioGroup1CheckBoxClick(Sender : TObject);
  BEGIN
    IF AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.CheckBox.Checked THEN BEGIN
      IF AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.Tag>=0 THEN AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.ItemIndex:=AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.Tag;
      AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.Tag:=-1
    END ELSE BEGIN
      AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.Tag:=AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.ItemIndex;
      AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.ItemIndex:=-1
    END
  END;
```

to the OnCheckBoxClick event. It will use the AdvOfficeRadioGroup's Tag property to store the previously selected ItemIndex so that it can be restored when you check the checkbox again.

Comment: I want the selection removed (emptied). Not kept.

Comment: Then delete the line "IF AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.Tag>=0 THEN AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.ItemIndex:=AdvOfficeRadioGroup1.Tag;" from the code.

Comment: It works fine here. Could you elaborate on what "does not work" means? What happens when you uncheck the checkbox, and what did you expect to happen?